# SwiftUI: calling a method from nested view

Tags: ios, mvvm, swiftui, combine

I am pretty nw to SwiftUI, and to make my code more readable, I usually break my views into smaller views.

Let's say I have a viewModel, what is the best way to call a method of my viewModel from a nested view? Right now I am passing around my ViewModel as a parameter of every nested view, but I don't find it very optimal and clean...

Is there a way to notify MyMainView that the button of HeaderSubview was tapped ? Can I use Combine for example?

**ViewModel**

```
class MyViewModel {
    func fetchSomeData() {
        print("Fetching Some Data")
    }
}
```

**MainView**

```
struct MyMainView: View {

    var myViewModel = MyViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        HeaderView(viewModel: myViewModel)
    }
}

struct HeaderView: View {
    var viewModel: MyViewModel

    var body: some View {
        HeaderSubview(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}

struct HeaderSubview: View {
    var viewModel: MyViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Button("Search") {
            // I want to call my View Model method here
            viewModel.fetchSomeData()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make your class ObservableObject and inject it as environment object, so any subview can use it and main view would be able to observe it.

Something like

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loading = false
    func fetchSomeData() {
        loading = true
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            print("Fetching Some Data")
            // ... long activity here
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.loading = false
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct MyMainView: View {
    
    @StateObject var myViewModel = MyViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        HeaderView().environmentObject(myViewModel)
        if myViewModel.loading {
            Text("Loading...")
        }
    }
}

struct HeaderView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HeaderSubview()
    }
}

struct HeaderSubview: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MyViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Button("Search") {
            // I want to call my View Model method here
            viewModel.fetchSomeData()
        }
    }
}
```